# Remove HTML tags and save scraped data to CSV file using Python 3 and Beautiful Soup 4

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape data from a table on a web page and then saving it into a CSV file using Python 3 and Beautiful Soup 4.  I have been able to extract the data, but I haven't been able to remove the tags around the data or find a way to save it to a CSV file.  I've combed through previously asked questions and attempted to apply those methods, but I'm still coming up short on solving this problem.

Here is my script:

```
import csv
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url="enter url here"
r=requests.get(url)
soup=BeautifulSoup(r.content,"lxml")

table=soup.find("table", attrs={"class":"smsEvents"})

list_rows=[]
for row in table.find_all('tr'):
    list_cells=[]
    for cell in row.find_all('td'):
        list_cells.append(cell)
    list_rows.append(list_cells)
print(list_rows)
```

Here is a sample of what the print command returns:

```
&amp;nbsp                             </td>, <td class="rel119 carrier">
&amp;nbsp                             </td>], [<td class="rel46 carrier">
                                    0.00
                                </td>, <td class="rel47 carrier">
                                    0.00
                                </td>, <td class="rel48 carrier">
                                    0.00
```

The table contains about 25 variables(rows) that are recorded every month(columns). I believe the `&amp;nbsp` entries correspond to rows that separate the variables into different categories.

Ideally, I would like to remove these tags and then save the output to a CSV file.  I am very new to python, and data scraping, so any and all help is very much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: post url or the table's html code

Comment: 404 Not found.....

Comment: post the table's html code in your question, this will be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import csv
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url="https://ai.fmcsa.dot.gov/SMS/Carrier/1000196/History.aspx"
r=requests.get(url)
soup=BeautifulSoup(r.content,"lxml")

table=soup.find("table", attrs={"class":"smsEvents"})
with open('a.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for tr in table('tr'):
        row = [t.get_text(strip=True) for t in tr(['td', 'th'])]
        writer.writerow(row)
```

out:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using `lxml` here instead of BeautifulSoup (directly. Try something like this:

```
from lxml import html
res=requests.get(url)
node = html.fromstring(res.content)
cells = node.xpath('//table[@class="smsEvents"]/tr/td')
```

Notice you can you the full xpath instead of iterating through each child element of the parent table to get the cells.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion David.  I will look into doing this again, but with lxml instead.